# Scraped data in Node does not appear in HTML page

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

Project: scrape the numbers of raised funds from 4 crowd funding links, and display all of those amounts on one page in real-time for live results

I've created a node application using express and have successfully scraped data from multiple sites (of which the results show up in my terminal's console), but now I am wanting for that data to appear in a specific part of my homepage HTML under id="".

I don't want to save to a database because I want the amounts that are presented on the HTML page to be the exact number that is populated once the page loads and scrapes.

Here's some code (from my server.js file):

```
request('https://www.blah.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var unitedData = $('.cta-title').children().first().text();
      console.log("Manchester: " + unitedData);
  } $('#raised-united').append(unitedData);
});
```

X4 (one for each link) all held in a "function scrape(){}" tag.
This code executes this in my terminal: [terminal's console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uY7O.png) so I know it works.

But the html that I have (index.html):

```
            <div class="col" id="numbers">
                <h2 id="raised-united"></h2>
                <h3 id="outOf"> of $5,000</h3>
            </div>
```

is unaltered...

Here is my server.js file:

```
//dependencies
var express = require("express");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//setting port
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
//start express
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(router);

function scrape(){
//scrapes Gooners crowdrise link
request('https://www.crowdrise.com/o/en/campaign/austin-goonersupperninety', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var goonersData = $('.cta-title').children().first().text();
      $('#raised-gooners').append(goonersData);
      console.log("Gooners: " +goonersData);
  }
});

//scrapes Austin Reds crowdrise link
request('https://www.crowdrise.com/o/en/campaign/austin-reds-and-upper-ninety', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var redsData = $('.cta-title').children().first().text();
      $('#raised-reds').append(redsData);
      console.log("Reds: " + redsData);
  }
});

//scrapes Austin Spurs crowdrise link
request('https://www.crowdrise.com/o/en/campaign/austin-spurs-and-upper-ninety', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var spursData = $('.cta-title').children().first().text();
      $('#raised-spurs').append(spursData);
      console.log("Spurs: " + spursData);

  }
});

//scrapes Austin Manchester crowdrise link
request('https://www.crowdrise.com/o/en/campaign/austinmanch esterunitedupperninety', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var unitedData = $('.cta-title').children().first().text();
      console.log("Manchester: " + unitedData);
  } $('#raised-united').append(unitedData);
});
};


app.listen(PORT, function() {
 console.log("App running on port" + PORT);
});

//directs server to homepage
module.exports = function(router){
router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("public/index.html");
});
}

scrape();
```

Comment: Unless you're not posting your code, it doesn't look like you're generating HTML at all.  The `.append()` call that you're doing is just modifying the HTML you've fetched from `blah.com`, which doesn't appear to be used by you further.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Then is there a way to link the var unitedData to my index.html page?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you're otherwise getting information. Can you show the whole route handler in which that request and scrape is happening, and also the HTML page you want it to go into?  Are you using clientside javascript and an API, or are you rendering HTML using Pug or Handlebars on the server?

Comment: I don't have the scrape function in a route handler, it is just as is in the server.js file because I want it to execute every time the page is opened. I want that data to be scraped and updated every time the page is visited - without the user having to click or doing anything.

Comment: That's not how that works.  If it's in the server.js file and *not* in a route handler, it's going to run only one time, when the application starts.  If you want it to run every time a page is visited, it needs to be either a route handler or middleware for that page.  Please show your server.js file so we can advise you.

Comment: what API would I need to do clientside javascript?

Comment: You'd need to expose an endpoint that renders your scraped data in whatever format your clientside javascript expects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Express' templating functionality together with a templating engine such as Pug, EJS or Handlebars to render a html template dynamically in order to display your data.